# Check if all characters are 'X'

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table:

```
COL
---
XXY
YXX
XXX
NULL
```

I want to filter out the rows which don't consist of all 'X's.
Expected output:

```
COL
---
XXX
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `REGEXP_LIKE` here:

```sql
SELECT COL
FROM yourTable
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(COL, '^X+$');  -- ^X+$ means all X from start to end
```

Another similar version:

```sql
SELECT COL
FROM yourTable
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(COL, '[^X]');  -- this means no non X present
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option(without using a *regular expression*) might be using

```
WITH t(col) AS
(
 SELECT 'XXY' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'YXX' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'XXX' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT  NULL FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'XX ' FROM dual 
)
SELECT *
  FROM t
 WHERE REPLACE(NVL(col,'Y'),'X') IS NULL;

COL
----
XXX
```

without forgetting the case `col = NULL` through use of a `NVL()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax (assuming you are using MySQL database 5.6 or greater version):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE col_name REGEXP '^X+$';
```

Comment: OP is using Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want/have regexp then:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (   Select 'XXY' "COL" From dual Union All
            Select 'YXX' "COL" From dual Union All
            Select 'XXX' "COL" From dual Union All
            Select null "COL" From dual 
        )
Select  COL 
From    tbl
Where   Length(Nvl(COL, 'Z')) - Length( Replace(  Upper(Nvl(COL, 'Z')), 'X', '')) Is Null

COL
---
XXX
```

This covers both small 'x' and capital 'X' if needed and returns original COL value